# Remove underline from link in e-mail signature on mobile screen with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the simplest html/css code that I'm using for e-mail signatures, and I'm trying to remove the underline from the links. I store the .htm document in the folder where Outlook looks for signatures. It works fine on a PC screen, but when I look at it later in the iPhone (whether it's in the Outlook app, Mail app or Gmail app), the underlines are there. Here is a sample:

```html
<html>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 287; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-family: Courier; background-color:#353535;">
<tbody><tr><td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px; padding-bottom:25px; padding-top:25px; "><a href="mailto:name@domain.com" style="color: white; text-decoration: none !important;">name@domain.com</a></td></tr>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
</html>
```

What's so strange is that if I send the .htm document as an attachment, and view it in on the iphone, it works fine (i.e. no underlines), even though I'm using the same e-mail apps to view it as when it's embedded directly into the e-mail.

As you have probably figured, I'm a total rookie, but I have googled this for days without finding a solution. Appreciate any help!

Edit: I have also tried by setting the color of the underline to the same as the table background (style="text-decoration-color:#353535"), but the result is the same. It works on PC screen, but not iPhone. The blue underline is extremely persistent!

Comment: Have you tried (text-decoration: none;) ?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I'm trying.

Comment: Does it happen only with Iphone? or any phone?

Comment: You can try a trick. 1st you need to save your above html code like **email.html** and open on Chrome/Firefox Browser and then **Select all** page i.e. (Ctrl+A) after selected then **Copy** (Ctrl+C) and **PASTE** (Ctrl+V)  inside **Signature Area** then check underline bar. I hope this will help you

Comment: @Koithé, I have only tried iphone so far.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam I tried that just now, but unfortunately, it didn't work either.

Comment: @LarsLind Are you tried with Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam on PC, I'm using Chrome. But what matters is where it doesn't work, which is the three different mail apps on iPhone. Now I just discovered that on gmail.com (in chrome) it also doesnt work.

Comment: @LarsLind Ok so now try on **Firefox browser**. So open your *Gmail* account on Firefox browser and also **email.html page** and then follow above instructions like select all and copy then paste inside signature area. I tested and both devices *PC* and *iPhone* working fine without underline.

Answer (score 0):

please try this approach, as Outlook, and other mail services tend to have problems with text-decoration:none (one can assume it's because of security concerns)

```
<a href="mailto:name@domain.com" style="color: white;">
   <span style="text-decoration:none">name@domain.com</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. In fact, with that method, the underline appears even on the PC screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<a href="mailto:name@domain.com" style="color: white;">
   <span style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;">name@domain.com</span>
</a>
```

The !important tag should rule over the web-based email clients' default style, thus leaving no underline.
Also, you can find a lot of information about email clients and their behaviour here:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/link-element/link-in-body/

Comment: It seems to be that the <span> tag inside the <a> tag does not work at all. I wasn't aware that the !important tag should be added to a separate tag so that it's repeated with and without it. But anyway, I tried that, both in a <span> element and in the <a> element, and still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Try on **Firefox** browser. So open your `Gmail` account & `email.html` page on Firefox browser after that follow instructions like **Select all** (Ctrl+A) and **Copy** (Ctrl+C) then **Paste** (Ctrl+V) inside `Signature Area`. I tested on both devices `PC & iPhone` so Its working fine without underline.
I hope this trick will solve your problem.

```html
<html>
<style>
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}    
</style>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 287; vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-family: Courier; background-color:#353535;"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px; padding-bottom:25px; padding-top:25px;"><a href="mailto:name@domain.com" style="color:white; text-decoration:none!important; text-decoration: none"><p style="text-decoration: none; margin: 0;">name@domain.com</p></a></td></tr></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Just to be sure, when you're saying I should paste it into the signature area, do you mean I should create a new signature in Outlook and paste it there?

Is the idea that Firefox should rewrite the code into something that's more robust? If so, what's the code that you get?